# for this condition , the pipeline didn't trigger ? why?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, rules

[rules:

- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-][0-9]+/i'
  when: always
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^SPRINT[-][0-9]+/i'
  when: never ]
- If I add like this , its triggers, for the pipeline only for (sprint) name related branches but I want the rules like

[ rules:

- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-][0-9]+/i'
  when: always
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^SPRINT[-][0-9]+/i'
  when: never]
  -If I gave like this, its doesn't trigger for sprint related branches. I want to run the pipeline for (sprint)named branches and also default branch and also specific named branches like dev , stage which I'm using in a single command line
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  If I split the command also, I doesn't works
  for eg:
  [rules:

  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: always
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^SPRINT[-_][0-9]+/i'
    when: never
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH ||  $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'dev'
    when: always
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH ||  $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != 'dev'
    when: never]- It doesn't trigger in dev branch
    . can you please anyone help me to sort it out

Cyril I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are evaluated one by one and evaluation stops on the first expression that evaluates to true. Your first two regex rules (`=~` then `!~` for the same regex pattern) will prevent any further rules from being evaluated because one of those two expressions will always evaluate true.

Comment: [- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+/i)) 

    when: always 

  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "dev" || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT[0-9]+/i)) 

    when: never] ......... now I'm using this. It works @sytech